# Why does this throw up a syntax error because of my colon?

Tags: python

Just starting out with Python and I'm getting quite frustrated with by I'm getting the error 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' with an arrow pointing to the colon? Does anyone know why this may be?

```
def rotateRx:
    return x[:-1] + [-1]
    
x = [1,2,3,4]

rotateRx(x)
```

Comment: You probably meant `rotateRx(x):`. Calling the function `rotateR` rather than `rotateRx` would have made that typo easier to spot.

Comment: For future question please add comments in the shown code where you get the errors, and please also copy-paste the full and complete error output into the question. That's especially important as you say there's an error with the `:`, but you have *two* of them and you don't tell us which one.

Answer (score 3):

Define your function with the parameter you plan to pass into it.

```
def rotateRx(x):
    return x[:-1] + [-1]
```

Python functions are always declared with a parameter list, even if it is empty.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks a lot for that my dude :)

Comment: @anonuser you should accept the answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You've not given any parameters as well as you've not put paranthesis. Try putting paranthesis and run your code. Also, you've just returned the value, not printed, printing it will display the value. Edited code:

```
def rotateRx(x):
    return x[:-1]+[-1]
x=[1,2,3,4]
print(rotateRx(x))
```